# Changing vertical scroll to horizontal scroll?

Tags: css

I apologize for the terrible title.

I'm running into an issue. I have a couple elements, by name they are:

```
-page
 -graph-container
  -lots of elements
 -selector
```

The graph-container element and selector are to be inline next to each other with the selector floating right. The graph-container element is supposed to have a lot of elements all next to each other (on the same line), thereby making a scrollbar in the x coordinate.

For the life of me, I can't get this to work. The current CSS goes like this:

```
-page - width: 820 (applies correctly)
 -container - height: 500px; width: 620; display: inline-block; overflow: scroll;
  -lots of elements - display:inline;
 -selector - float:right; display:inline-block;
```

What this gets me is a vertical scroll with the elements wrapping around the end onto the next line. What I would like is all the elements to be on the same row, and the scroll be left and right/horizontal.

Comment: It would really help if you post relevant parts of your HTML & CSS code. Trim out all the not important bits and past the result here.

Answer (score 1):

idem, white-space, but you have to distribute it where needed and reset where not.

another way, not as usual as white space, is to set a colum-width.

It will build as many column needed to **fit in the height of its container**.(set a width, else it's one line :) )

To display your 2 main containers aside each other, there's floatting, inline-block + white-space, and display:table/table-cell usually used.

Here is a mixed of possibilities.Test & Pick up the one that feet best your point.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/kvLzu http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/full/kvLzu .
Don't hesitate to fork and play with, nothing will get broken )

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out and this could be helpful for anyone Googleling. Try adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x:scroll;
```

To the container.